# Limit the length of a string to 10

Tags: perl

I have written a small script to convert decimals to hexadecimal.

```
my $hex_num = sprintf("0000%X",$dec_num);
```

The decimal numbers are in the range of **1,000,000 - 5,999,999,999**.
I have to add leading zero's but my field is limited to 10.  When I convert big values, I capture hex **0000989680**, but when I convert **5,999,999,999** the output **0000165A0BBFF**.  I need to be able to remove the extra leading zero's and just have **0165A0BBFF** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $hex_of_num = sprintf("%010X", $num);
```